# How to save or load properties of filter in DirectShow

Tags: com, directshow, directshow.net

I have a source filter in the graph of my application. I could show the properties page by using standard API (from oleaut32.dll - `OleCreatePropertyFrame`, see [Displaying a Filter's Property Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375480)).

But how to save/serialize and load/deserialize the filter properties from code?
I'm using DirectShow.NET to build graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `IPersistStream` interface from the filter and use [`IPersistStream.Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691473) to request writing of persistent settings into stream. [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680568) back similarly.

Comment: should i pas any file to the save() method. Can u give some sample code.

Comment: does all filters implement IPersistStream interface

Comment: You pass stream, not file (or not necessarily a file - the stream might be backed by file, memory etc). The filters don't have to implement `IPersistStream`.